# How to get random value from property from one List?

Tags: c#

I have a List of 10,000 entries of type `Element`:

```
public class Element
{
    public Element()
    {
        this.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set };
}
```

And I have another List of 5,000 entries of type `Link`:

```
public class Link
{
    public Link(Guid ElementOne, Guid ElementTwo)
    {
        this.ElementOne = ElementOne;
        this.ElementTwo = ElementTwo;
    }

    public Guid ElementOne { get; set; }
    public Guid ElementTwo { get; set; }
}
```

I am populating my Lists here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10,000; i++)
    this.ListOfElements.Add(new Element());

for (int i = 0; i < 5,000; i++)
{
    this.ListOfLinks.Add(new Link(need ElementOne, need ElementTwo));
}
```

I am not sure what to pass for `ElementOne` and `ElementTwo`. I want to grab a random Id from the Element List (`Element.Id`) for both parameters and ensure they're unique (`ElementOne` could never be `ElementTwo`).

Comment: You need to keep track of elements you are adding or quering ListOfLinks everytime you want to add something, and adding a method to give you next one to add

Comment: So, can ElementOne and ElementTwo NEVER repeat? Or do you just want to avoid linking 1 - 1. Is linking 1-2 and then 1-3 ok? Do you need to avoid linking 1-2, then later linking 1-2 again?

Comment: Oh sorry, I wasn't clear - I just don't want 1 - 1. 1 - 2 repeated is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you just need two random numbers. You can compare and repoll if you happen to get a duplicate.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5,000; i++)
{
    int ele1 = Random.NextInt(10000);
    int ele2 = Random.NextInt(10000);

    while(ele1 == ele2){
        ele2 = Random.NextInt(10000);
    }
    this.ListOfLinks.Add(new Link(ListOfElements[ele1], ListOfElements[ele2]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give a random array of the index to your list.  So you can take randIndex[0] and randIndex[1] to get two random items.

```
            Random rand = new Random();
            List<string> myList = new List<string>() { "a","b","c"};
            int[] randIndex = myList.Select((x,i) => new {i = i, rand = rand.Next()}).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.i).ToArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to find next element which is not used, also using `.OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid())` to get random element

```
private Element GetNextAvaibaleElement() {
  var usedElementIds = listOfLinks.Select(i => i.ElementOne).Union(listOfLinks.Select(i => i.ElementTwo));
  return listOfElements.Where(i => !usedElementIds.Contains(i.Id)).OrderBy(i => Guid.NewGuid()).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

and then get two available elements

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5,000; i++)
{
    this.ListOfLinks.Add(new Link(GetNextAvaibaleElement().Id,GetNextAvaibaleElement().Id));
}
```

See this dotnet fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o5iF1Q)

Answer (score -1):

Create an instance of the `Random` class somewhere.

E.g.

```
static Random rdm = new Random();
```

Then, use this `rdm` instance to generate a random integer, delete that element from the list (so as not to reuse it), and keep going until you deplete your list.

```
List<Element> listOfElements; // list of 10k Elements

for (int i = 0; i < 5,000; i++)
{
    int r = rdm.Next(listOfElements.Count);
    Element elementOne = listOfElements[r]; 
    listOfElements.RemoveAt(r);
    r = rdm.Next(listOfElements.Count);
    Element elementTwo = listOfElements[r]; 
    this.ListOfLinks.Add(new Link(elementOne, elementTwo));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One approach to solving this is to create a list of integers representing the indexes into the `ListOfElements`, then order that list in a random way. Then you can simply reference items in the `ListOfElements` by index, sequentially walking through the randomized index list:

```
private static void Main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) ListOfElements.Add(new Element());

    // Create a randomly-ordered list of indexes to choose from
    var rnd = new Random();
    var randomIndexes = Enumerable.Range(0, ListOfElements.Count)
        .OrderBy(i => rnd.NextDouble()).ToList();

    // Now use our random indexes to pull unique items from the Element list
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i += 2)
        ListOfLinks.Add(new Link(ListOfElements[randomIndexes[i]].Id,
            ListOfElements[randomIndexes[i + 1]].Id));

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```